# Time Based Animation - Increment a number over a set time (pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, timer, numbers

I want to animate a number from 0 and end at a chosen value.

It must increment over a set time e.g. 1 second (time-based).

I need a pure JavaScript solution (not jQuery).

I have something like this:

```
var animator = {};

animator.animate = null;

animator.settings = {
    elapsedTime: 0, //The elapsed time (used for animation)
    lastTime: 0, //The last time
    startTime: 0, //The current time
    speed: 1000 //How long it should animate
};

animator.increment = function (el, currVal, endVal) {
    var settings = this.settings,
        lastTime,
        self = this,
        startTime;

    settings.startTime = Date.now(); //Get the current time

    startTime = settings.startTime; //Cache the startTime
    lastTime = settings.lastTime; //Cache the lastTime

    //If the lastTime is not equal to 0
    if (lastTime !== 0) {
        settings.elapsedTime = startTime - lastTime; //Update the elapsed time
    }

    settings.lastTime = settings.startTime; //Update the last time

    //If the elapsed time has not passed the speed e.g. 1 second
    if (settings.elapsedTime >= settings.speed) {
        //Add the final value and clear the animation

        clearInterval(this.animate); //Stop animating
    } else {
        //Update the number
        if (currVal < endVal) {
            currVal += settings.speed * settings.elapsedTime;
        } else {
            currVal = endVal;
        }

        el.innerHTML = '&pound;' + currVal; //Update the HTML
    }

    this.animate = setInterval(function () {
        self.increment(el, currVal, endVal)
    }, 1000 / 60); //60 FPS
};

animator.increment(document.getElementById('num'), 0, 1234);
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

**It increments too fast, the transition is not smooth and it sometimes does not stop animating.**

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was created by the following line:

```
settings.lastTime = settings.startTime;
```

You only use that for continuous animation e.g. a game loop

I've neatened up my code and answered it based off another solution somebody gave me.

```
var animator = {};

animator.animateNum = function (el, currVal, endVal) {
    var elapsedTime = 0, //The elapsed time (used for animation)
        fps = 1000 / 60, //60 fps (can be 16)
        lastTime = Date.now(), //The last time
        duration = 1000, //How fast it should animate
        increment = (endVal / duration) * fps, //Work out the increment amount
        update = null; //Where we attach the interval

    //Setup the interval
    update = setInterval(function () {
        elapsedTime = Date.now() - lastTime; //Work out the elapsed time

        //Check the elapsed time has not passed the duration
        if (elapsedTime < duration) {
            //Do the animation
            currVal += increment; //Increase the value
            el.innerHTML = '&pound' + parseFloat(currVal, 10).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            //Else, don't do the animation
            el.innerHTML = '&pound' + parseFloat(endVal, 10).toFixed(2); //Update it to the last value
            clearInterval(update); //Clear the interval
        }
    }, fps);
};

animator.animateNum(document.getElementById('num'), 0, 1005.99);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Levyg475/1/

Cheers!